# Count all characters in string but spaces

Tags: c

How can I count sum of characters in string excluding blank spaces?! I wrote a code but it counts blank spaces too. Any suggestions? here is what I have:

```
void main()
{
char str[100];
int len, space;

printf( "Enter string:\n ");
printf("\n");
gets(str);

len = strlen(str);

printf("\n");
printf("\n No.of characters in string is %d " , len );

getch();
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/).

Comment: Obligatory warning to use `fgets` not `gets`.

Comment: You've made no effort to "count" anything. You've used `strlen()` to get the total length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over string and check all characters, counting only non-space chars. Something like:

```
int i;
int len = strlen(str);
int count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char c = str[i];
    if ( /* check that char is not space */ )
        count++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can count all space characters and then calculate `len - nspaces`.

Answer (score 4):

For simple spaces try this

```
len = strlen(str);
int nchar = 0
for(int i = 0; i != len; i++) {
   if(str[i] != ' ') {
       nchar++;
   }
}
printf("nchar = %d\n", nchar);
```

For all whitespace ( space, tab, newline ) try this:

```
#include <ctype.h> // this line must be in the top of the file
len = strlen(str);    
int nchar = 0;
for(int i = 0; i != len; i++) {
   if(!isspace(str[i])) {
       nchar++;
   }
}
printf("nchar = %d\n", nchar);
```

Other ways you might see in code are:

```
int nchar = 0;
for(char *p = str; *p; nchar += (*p++ != ' '));
```

and

```
int nchar = 0;
for(char *p = str; *p; nchar += isspace(*p++) == 0);
```

But those are less obvious.